# Selenium Instagram Login - Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

```
from selenium import webdriver

userName = "myusername123"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input').send_keys(userName)
```

Error

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*. [@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input"}
```

I'm trying to make a login in Instagram using selenium but I can't reach the  username box with XPath

Comment: I managed login here: https://github.com/alicakil/SeleniumCrawler. Today works, but it may not work if instagram updates front-end for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

See, there is name attribute available, you can try with that as below :-

```
driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(userName)
```

`name` is always a reliable locator than `xpath`

if the above does not work, you can try with the **Explicit waits** as well :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

userName = "myusername123"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'username'))).send_keys(userName)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(( By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys('somepassword')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(( By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Log In']/.."))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check with the `explicitWait` and use the `name` attribute

```
username=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='username']")))
username.send_keys("userName")

password=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='password']")))
password.send_keys("password")
```

**import**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
```